# No shades IN Unity OBJECTS

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I have a problem, I'm sure there is a solution when I add texture to an element, and I change to Unit -> Texture to look beautiful, shadows disappear, I don't know the solution,
Please help, creative people, thank you :)

any way to use a lightmap png file? I think is the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the material on the surface uses an Unlit shader, then the material will not be lit, just as the name suggests. Consequently it will not have shadows change its appearance.

If you stil want to go for a flatter look while keeping shadows, I would suggest you use a cel shader. You can build one with Shader Graph, just google 'cel shader unity'.

Comment: :( NOT WORK WITH ME! I MEAN, Can you specify pls :)?

Comment: You have light sources in your scene that illuminate your materials. Each material has a shader, which has certain properties how to handle that incoming light. For instance, most default shaders support something like roughness values. Depending on what value is set, the material will look very smooth or very rough when light illuminates it. If there is no light touching the material, its dark. Unlt shaders ignore this and will always be "bright". To avoid this, use a shader that is not unlit. I would suggest you read up on shaders a bit: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Shaders.html